# Why does the square bracket not scale up?

Tags: brackets, delimiters, size

I'm using `\left [ \right ]` to scale the bracket up to the height of the expression inside.
[image]

However, it works as expected in the first line, bit not in the remaining two lines. Could you elaborate on this issue?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,mathtools,listings,sectsty,amsthm,enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb,bbm,bbm,amsmath,hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{Nadaraya-Watson estimator}

\begin{definition}\label{risk}~
\begin{align}
\mathcal R \left (\hat f_{n,h,h'} \right) &\triangleq \mathbb E \left [ \left \| \hat f_{n,h,h'} - f \right \|_2^2 \right ] = \mathbb E \left [ \int_{\mathbb R} \left (\hat f_{n,h,h'} (x) -f(x) \right )^2 \mathrm dx \right ]\\
\mathcal R \left ( \hat a_{n, h} \right) &\triangleq \mathbb E \left [ \left \| \hat a_{n,h} - pf \right \|_2^2 \right ]\\
\mathcal R \left ( \hat p_{n, h'} \right) &\triangleq \mathbb E \left [ \left \| \hat p_{n,h'} - p \right\|_2^2 \right ]
\end{align}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm afraid that you're looking to the problem from the wrong side.

In *all* three lines, `\left` and `\right` do exactly what's expected from them. One thing to keep in mind is that up to a certain size, delimiters grow in discrete steps using specially designed glyphs; only above a threshold the delimiters are built up with repeating pieces (but even then not all sizes are possible).

If you compare the left-hand sides in your formulas you can notice that `\hat{f}` and `\hat{a}` have very different height, so `\left(\hat{f}\right)` chooses `\Big` size for the delimiters (similarly for the norm in the right-hand side). This is really oversized, but TeX has no other possibility, if you *really* want that the delimiters entirely cover the symbol.

An example with less distraction:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
(\hat{f}_n) \quad \bigl(\hat{f}_n\bigr) \quad \Bigl(\hat{f}_n\Bigr) \quad \left(\hat{f}_n\right)
\\
(\hat{a}_n) \quad \bigl(\hat{a}_n\bigr) \quad \Bigl(\hat{a}_n\Bigr) \quad \left(\hat{a}_n\right)
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now aesthetic considerations come into play and they are a bit subjective, so I'll try to corroborate my opinion also with mathematical considerations.

The comparison between the `\hat{f}` and `\hat{a}` cases shows that the automatically chosen delimiters in the former are way too large. Possibly `\big` size might be better, but in my opinion it's not at all necessary: fully “covering” the symbols hides the fact that the *main* object is “f”, which has a modifier above it.

So, how would I render the formulas?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\mathcal{R}(\hat{f}_{n,h,h'}) &\triangleq
  \mathbb{E} \bigl[\, \lVert\hat{f}_{n,h,h'} - f \rVert_2^2 \,\bigr] =
  \mathbb{E} \biggl[ \int_{\mathbb{R}} (\hat{f}_{n,h,h'} (x) -f(x) )^2 \diff x \biggr]
\\
\mathcal{R}(\hat{a}_{n, h}) &\triangleq
  \mathbb{E} \bigl[\, \lVert\hat{a}_{n,h} - pf \rVert_2^2 \,\bigr]
  \vphantom{\smash[t]{\bigg|}}
\\
\mathcal{R}(\hat{p}_{n, h'}) &\triangleq
  \mathbb{E} \bigl[\, \lVert\hat{p}_{n,h'} - p \rVert_2^2 \,\bigr]
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Points to notice:

1. No `\left` and `\right`
2. `\big` size for the brackets `[]` due to the exponent in the norm
3. A thin space helps better than big size in reducing clutter

Better symmetry overall and less strain to the eye.

The `\vphantom` trick is to get equal vertical spacing in the equation numbers. It adds to the middle equation a depth the same size as the top equation (the height is not considered due to `\smash[t]` that zeroes the height).

I always suggest `\diff` for the differential symbol, so you can change your mind about it being upright or italic (the latter would be better, in my opinion, but it's personal taste) with just a change in the definition.

And, finally, it is `\mathcal{R}`, not `\mathcal R`; similarly for `\hat` and `\mathbb`.

Comment: What’s wrong with `\mathcal R` etc.? I use such constructions all the time.

Comment: Also, for differentials, I personally prefer using [`diffcoeff`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/diffcoeff) rather than defining my own `\diff` command.

Comment: @bradrn I've mixed opinions about `diffcoeff`. True, `\mathcal R` produces the same as `\mathcal{R}`, but I can't recommend using it. When you'll try `\mathcal AB`, you'll know why.

Comment: Of course it only works for one character, but I tend to view this as a feature: e.g. `\hat x_0` does the right thing (to take an example I used just yesterday). In the case of your example, I’d tend to prefer `\mathcal A\mathcal B` for semantic reasons. Also, what’s wrong with `diffcoeff`?

Comment: @bradrn Nothing wrong with the package, but it tends to overdo…

Answer (score 5):

the size of the delimiter aims to be a fraction smaller than the content (`\delimitershortfall` parameter) but jumps in discrete steps so these things happen, it would look better if you chose the sizes by hand with `\bigl[...\bigr]` or whatever size you need